# How can I mount a local directory to an existing docker container?

Tags: docker, containers

I want to mount a local directory from a private cloud to an container there using -v flag. When I run `docker run -it -v "$(pwd)":/name-of-the-folder-inside-container existing-container bash`, the directory gets mounted. However, I go to the container running this command `docker run -it existing-container bash`, I don't see the directory that mounted earlier. It is the same container that I am trying to access using the second command but the filesystem doesn't show me the folder in which I mounted the local directory.

`docker run -it -v "$(pwd)":/name-of-the-folder-inside-container existing-container bash`

Comment: It‘s probably **not** the same container, because you can’t AFAIK use `docker run` on existing containers. It‘s either `docker exec` to „attach" to a running container or `docker start` to restart a stopped container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `docker run -it existing-container bash` you're not actually connecting to the old container with the same name, but generating a new container from the same *image*.

Docker run is used to spin up a new container.
Docker start will start an existing, but currently stopped container.
Docker exec is used to run a command on an existing container.

Try to use `docker exec -it existing-container bash` when accessing the container again after initially creating it with the mounted volume instead.

Comment: Why is this an answer? The response still does not seem to answer the main question.  The main question is how to attach volume to an EXISTING container....and not trying to recreate a new container with mounted volume. 

So the response, I thought, should be either "can't be done", or "can be done" with an illustration.

Comment: That may well be the question written in the title, but if you read his whole question, it is clear his problem was a misunderstanding of how starting and running containers work, not how to mount file systems after the fact. My answer is valid in relation to the question body, if anything the title of the question should be changed.